# Fish weight - Normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the weight of fish distributes by Normal distribution, with $\mu = 900$ and  ${\displaystyle \sigma ^{2}}\ = 150^2$. What is the  probability that out of $10$ fish that were chosen randomly, at least $2$ and at most $9$ are weighted not less than $667.5$?

So I assumed by the central limit theorem that the 10 fish got $\mu = 900$ and ${\displaystyle \sigma ^{2}}\ = 150^2/10$. When I'm trying to give this a standard score by $Z$ I get $Z= - 4.901$. When checking the $Z$ Table I can assume that the probability for the will be $1$.
So If it's $1$, so get $2<X<9$ is $1$ too? or I'm not in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes:**

CLT is not an option. The weight cannot be a singleton, but it must be "at least 667.5" or "at most 667.5". The probability to be exactly 667.5 is 0.

**Solution**

First: calculate the probability of one fish to be in that weight

Second: conclude with the binomial distribution

$P(X=k)= \binom{10}{k}p^k(1-p)^{10-k}$

where $p$ is the probability that one fish is in the desired weight and $k=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ are the number of successes

Comment: Thank you! So I calculated the probability for one fish and got $0.9394$ by the $Z$ table. And did what you suggested with the binomial distribution and got $0.464$. I have a question out of curiosity, I just did the binomial distribution for all cases, $X=2$, $X=3$ till I got to $X=9$.  is this the way or there's some shortcut?

Comment: @JustEquvilant : the complement probability. $1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=10)=0.464$